# Get values of all fields for an list of ids  without specifying their id in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

i have an sql query from which i am getting sum of weightage for all the answers linked to an agent. its working for me when i specify an agent id for example 1 .

but i would like to know

- is it possible without specify an agent id i get all the answers linked to all the agents that i have in db i am not getting idea how to do that am usind zend ?
- can an sql query be looped if i have an array of agents and make it return all the  weigtage of all the agent to return the agents weigtage for a specific question in an array form.

**table structure for tables**

**table structure for table agents**

agent_id // al agent ids 
1
2
3

**table structure for table answer**

answer_id // all answer ids     weigtage // to be addded has sum for each agent indivually
 11                              1
 12                              0
 13                             -1

**table structure for table customer survey**

// customer id          // fault id          // survey id 
      1                     1                       4
      2                     3                       5

**table structure for table faults**

fault_id     agent_id

// 3          3

//4           5                   //   all this is random data

**table structure for table response**

// response id       survey id   customer_id     answer id
response_id           sq_id         cs_id         answer_id

**table structure for table survey_question**

survey_id     question_id

**each answer is associated with an fault . and a fault with agent . customer takes a survey . fault with customer response . custome response cs_id to response . question is asscoacited with a particular survey. and ya its confusing a bit took me two days**

- i have 20 random agent ids and i need to kinda loop through them in mysql and get the result for each agent id . at present at a time i am getting for one agent.

---

```
SELECT SUM( weightage )
FROM answer a
WHERE a.answer_id
  IN (
    SELECT r.answer_id
    FROM response r, survey_question sq
    WHERE r.sq_id = sq.sq_id
      AND sq.survey_id =4
      AND sq.question_id =28
      AND r.cs_id
        IN (
          SELECT cs.cs_id
          FROM customer_survey cs, faults f
          WHERE cs.fault_id = f.fault_id
            AND agent_id =1
        )
  )`
```

the output of this query for an single agent is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
       [SUM( weightage )] => 2
    )
)
```

i would like the output to be like based on agent ids like

```
Array
(
//  agent id 1
     [1] => Array 
     (
         [SUM( weightage )] => 2
     )
// agent id 2
    [2] => Array 
    (
        [SUM( weightage )] => -1
    )
// agent id 3
    [3] => Array 
    (
        [SUM( weightage )] => 5
    )
// agent id 4
    [4] => Array 
    (
        [SUM( weightage )] => 4
    )
// agent id 5
    [5] => Array 
    (
        [SUM( weightage )] => 11
    )
)
```

Comment: Haven't time to look at it thorougherly.  However, the kind of situation you described normally indicates you need a GROUP BY

Comment: well do come back when u get time , i just got an idea may be it can be done through contrroller just loop through all the agent id and and put the query in that loop . and keep adding the result too an array . but it would have been if an query could have did so . i m working on controller for now :)

Comment: What you can achieve in one query - do so in one query. Jumping from php to mysql very often slows the program massively.

Comment: It would help massively if you could post a few records of each table and the expected result for that data :) ALWAYS do that

Comment: ya but the module am working on will only be for admins so page loading issuse will not be bothersome

Comment: And can you now post how the data looks in the tables? (what I asked for)

Comment: i have edited it a bit but i have got an answer already by other method

Answer (score 1):

without knowing your scheme its hard to give you a good advice. The basic keywords for you to find out more are [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/join.html) and [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/group-by-modifiers.html).

Your Query then should look something like this:

```
SELECT cs.agent_id, SUM (a.weightage) AS sum_weightage
 FROM customer_survey cs
  JOIN faults f ON cs.fault_id = f.fault_id
  JOIN response r ON r.cs_id = cs.cs_id
  JOIN answer a ON a.a.answer_id ON r.answer_id
  JOIN survey_question sq ON r.sq_id = sq.sq_id
 WHERE sq.survey_id = 4 AND sq.question_id =28 
 GROUP BY cs.agent_id
```

The output the would be something like:

```
array(
   array('agent_id' => 1, 'sum_weightage' => 12),
   array(...)
   ...
)
```

Thats not exactly what you want, but shold be nearest to your expectations.

Comment: thanks i have already solved it from controller by looping agent id through sql queries but its bit heavy on page like 10 seconds

Comment: do you have indices on all the foreign keys set?

Comment: it didnt work got this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON r.answer_id JOIN survey_question sq ON r.sq_id = sq.sq_id WHERE sq.survey_' at line 5

Comment: hey I think I gave you a good hint in the right direction (use JOINS and GROUP BY) - now its time for you to stand on your own feet

Comment: i know joins dont know how to use group by . ya i know am moving towards that .